# SQL Server 2008 : Character encoding

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, character-encoding, special-characters

I have 2 separate SQL server instances, one is our testing system and the other is our production system.  In the testing system, the value in the field (type: nvarchar(50)) appears like (a) listed below.  However, in the Production system it appears like (b) below --

a) Some – character

b) Some â€“ character

I have two questions :-

1. What difference in settings of the database/SQL instance would make the same character appear differently?
2. Is there a way to find the unicode equivalent of that special character, so I can get a more clear understanding of which language/keyboard this originates from? (This field is populated by a user form, and we have a global team of users)

Thanks.

Comment: For unicode values: SELECT UNICODE('â'); SELECT UNICODE('€')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this statement on both boxes.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

It sounds like you have different default Collations on the different servers.  If they are different, you'll have to then determine whether you want to/can make them both the same.

[This question on ServerFault should give you some guidance if that's the case.](https://serverfault.com/questions/19577/how-do-i-change-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-database)